# Show ImageView when click on ITEM of Adapter(Photos) of RecyclerView on Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, adapter, android-viewholder

I have a problem, i read about it and i cant do that on OnBindViewHolder, but i use this in other sites and always same error... 
After my error i use too, on LONG click to do one thing and it work correctly but before that i want to use on Clock normal, not long, for when i click, show an alertbox with image (i try to do this with imageview normal too, without alertbox)
but nothing, same error...

**I want with this to take on one photo of recyclerview, and open it from directory and "zoom" in alertbox...**

*The code*

```
public class Fotos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Fotos.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ImageItem> fotosLista;
    private ImageButton image;


    public Fotos(List<ImageItem> fotosLista, Context context) {
        this.fotosLista = fotosLista;
        this.context = context;


    }


    public Fotos() {

    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public View view;
       public ImageButton image;




        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen);


        }

    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);

        ViewHolder tvh = new ViewHolder(itemView);


        return tvh;

    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {

        final ImageItem item = fotosLista.get(pos);
        image = viewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(item.getImage(), 120, 120, false));


        viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File[] listFile;
                File file = new File("storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myDirectoryName/");
                listFile = file.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                    String path = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                    Bitmap bitmapMostrar = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);


                    ImageView mostrarImagen=(ImageView)viewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.mostrarImagen2);
                    mostrarImagen.setImageBitmap(bitmapMostrar);


                }
                    AlertDialog.Builder transferencia2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(viewHolder.view.getContext());
                    transferencia2.setView(R.layout.imagenzoom);
                    AlertDialog dialog2 = transferencia2.create();
                    dialog2.show();




            }
        });


        viewHolder.image.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder transferencia = new AlertDialog.Builder(viewHolder.view.getContext());
                transferencia.setMessage("¿Deseas enviar la foto al servidor?");
                transferencia.setTitle("Transferir/Cancelar ");
                transferencia.setPositiveButton("Transferir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        dialogInterface.cancel();


                        //Aquí va lo de la BD + Update




                    }


                });
                transferencia.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        //Aquí se cierra el alertBox y se cancela la transferencia.

                        dialogInterface.cancel();


                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog2 = transferencia.create();
                dialog2.show();


                return true;
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != fotosLista ? fotosLista.size() : 0);
    }
```

The problem is on OnBindViewHolder, on first onClick method...
****LogCat error:****

```
05-08 17:26:47.870 14576-14576/com.example.practicas_.arcadiatruck E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.practicas_.arcadiatruck, PID: 14576
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.practicas_.arcadiatruck.Fotos$1.onClick(Fotos.java:105)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
05-08 17:26:47.873 1135-4779/? W/ActivityManager:Force finishing activity com.example.practicas_.arcadiatruck/.ActividadFragments
```

The alertbox is a layout with only one image, i test it with android:src and drawable image on it and i click and it work... 
Thank u guys, i lose a lot of hours with this xD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line

```
image = viewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
```

And when you use `setImageBitmap` access the `image` like that

```
viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(yourImage);
```

**EDIT:**

There is a lot of stuff happening in your `onBindViewHolder` and you inflate your views (`findViewById`) in different places. All that work should be moved to a `ViewHolder` it will be much easier to manage.

First of all, you have this line twice `image = viewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);`, you don't need to do that, you only need to do it once, do it once in `ViewHolder` constructor and that's it.

Also  this line `ImageView mostrarImagen=(ImageView)viewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.mostrarImagen2);` is better off in your `ViewHolder` constructor and not in `onBindViewHolder`.

After that, remove the `View view` from your `ViewHolder` and remove this line from the constructor as well `view = itemView;`, no need to do that.

Now your `ViewHolder` constructor and declaration should look something like this:

```
public ImageButton image;
public ImageView mostrarImagen

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    mostrarImagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mostrarImagen2);
}
```

And when you use the `ImageButton` and the `ImageView` in `onBindViewHolder` don't do `findViewById` just use `viewHolder.image` and `viewHolder.mostrarImagen`.

Regarding your `onClickListener` and `onLongClickListener`, put them in your `ViewHolder` class, it's much cleaner. Put these lines in your `ViewHolder` constructor:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

Also, make sure that your `ViewHolder` implements `onClickListener` like this:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener
```

And then in your `ViewHolder` class override `onClickListener` and `onLongClickListener`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // your code        
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    // your code
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nope, not is the solution , is bad

Comment: @Chuflitas I'll edit my answer a bit later, you have several problems

Comment: Thank u man, nice answer! ^^ Ar the end i dont need your method i can use all in onbind successfully to my app , but i understand how work this... Thank u for your time :)